# Virtual host tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I'm a newbie in tomcat. If I create a virtual host in tomcat e.g. www.myapp.com, will it work for outside peole? Or it will work only in internal network?  I have a node in a domain and the name is very long so I will like to shorten it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualHosts are not magic: they only configure the server to route certain requests to a particular `<Host>` you have configured in Tomcat's `server.xml`. If you want `www.myapp.com` to resolve to a server of your choice (everywhere and not just on your local machine or something like that), you will need to modify the global DNS registry to map that host name to your server. Your domain registrar should provide the tools you need to accomplish that.